# Learning Scheme, trying to implement map

Tags: scheme, fold

I try to implement map using with fold in Scheme. 
I referenced this site: [ref1] http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/Towards_a_Standard_Library
The way I understand about fold =>
left-associate fold (foldl) folds/iterates from the first element. (forwards)
right-associate fold (foldr) folds/iterates from the last element. (backwards)
**[Q1] Do I understand correctly?**

From ref1 : the implementation of foldl, foldr

```
 `1) foldl (left-associate fold)`
  (define (foldl func accum lst)
   (if (null? lst)
        accum
        (foldl func (func accum (car lst)) (cdr lst))))

2) foldr (right-associate fold)
 (define (foldr func end lst)
   (if (null? lst)
      end
      (func (car lst) (foldr func end (cdr lst)))))
```

[=>] implement map using fold, ref1 also has map with foldr code, so that's it..

```
1) map implementation using foldr from ref1.
  (define (map func lst)      
     (foldr (lambda (x y) (cons (func x) y)) '() lst))

**[Q2] map impelementation using foldl from myself** 
  (define (fold-map-left pr list)
    (foldl 
       (lambda (sublist element) (cons (pr element) sublist))
       '() 
       list)
  what I get as the output...
  e.g. (fold-map-left (lambda(n) (expt n n)) '(1 2 3 4)) 
       output => (256 27 4 1): backwards
```

- I know that left associate fold folds/iterates backwards, so it will take the last first and put it into output..., then what can I do to make the output in right order ? and Is there anything else wrong in my code?

Comment: What is the output that you expect to get, and what is the output that you are actually getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, I believe your `foldl` implementation is a bit off, the usual way to implement it in Scheme would be (but make sure to read @JoshuaTaylor's comment to understand the consequences):

```
(define (foldl func accum lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      accum
      (foldl func
             (func (car lst) accum) ; here's the change
             (cdr lst))))
```

About the first question: both folds consume the input list from left-to-right, but they differ in the way that the output result is built: `foldl` accumulates the first input element at the beginning, and then accumulates the second element on top of the result, and so on; if we were building a list as output then the first element would be the last (and test your own implementation of `foldl` with this example, to see why I say it's a bit off):

```
(foldl cons '() '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(5 4 3 2 1)
```

On the other hand, `foldr` advances recursively until it reaches the empty list and then, as the recursion starts unwinding the last element gets accumulated first, and then the second-to-last on top of the result, and so on - thus preserving the same order of the input:

```
(foldr cons '() '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(1 2 3 4 5)
```

Regarding the second question: It'll be simpler to implement `map` in terms of `foldr`, because as we saw before it preserves input order. This is the same as yours, but with better formatting and variable names:

```
(define (map func lst)
  (foldr (lambda (ele acc)
           (cons (func ele) acc))
         '()
         lst))
```

But of course, we could use `foldl` and reverse the result at the end (or alternatively: reverse the list before passing it to `foldl`):

```
(define (map func lst)
  (reverse
   (foldl (lambda (ele acc)
            (cons (func ele) acc))
          '()
          lst)))
```

What's the idea of having both `foldl` and `foldr`? It's a trade-off (and make sure to read @ChrisJester-Young's comments for a discussion of the implementation concerns from a performance point of view). `foldr` will preserve the same order as the input when building the output, but it'll generate a recursive process that runs in space proportional to the size of the input: notice that `func` is executed *after* invoking the recursive call.

On the other hand `foldl` will build the output in reverse order, but it'll generate an iterative process that runs in constant space: notice that there is nothing left to do after invoking the recursive call, so it's tail-recursive and Scheme is optimized for efficiently handling this kind of recursion.

Comment: The left and right folding thing, for mapping, is a heap-stack tradeoff: for left folds, you're keeping a temporary list to reverse at the end, or you're generating a temporary reversed list to fold over. Olin Shivers, author of SRFI 1, argues that in such cases, preferring the stack (i.e., right fold) is a better tradeoff, because of data locality (stack frames are generally kept together, whereas cons cells can be all over the show) and ease of memory reclamation. You already know all that, of course, but the OP may find that useful.

Comment: My comment re heap/stack, of course, assumes a traditional calling mechanism; for implementations that use CPS for everything, well, everything's likely going to be heap-based anyway. :-)

Comment: Note that some languages would do the equivalent of what OP posted:  `(foldl func (func accum (car lst)) (cdr lst))`.  This has the nice property that in a left-associative fold, the initial value/accumulator is on the *left* side of the binary operator `func`.  So, e.g, fold(+,w,[x,y,z]) becomes (((w+x)+y)+z).  To do it the other way round, you'd end up with (z+(y+(x+w))), which seems to have much less claim (in my opinion) to being a left-associative fold over the list.  There's lots of variation in implementations, though.  This is what Common Lisp's `reduce` does, for instance.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Some language is Scheme. In the [R6RS report](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-4.html#node_idx_212): `(fold-left cons '(q) '(a b c)) ; ==> ((((q) . a) . b) . c)` but in [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#FoldUnfoldMap) `(fold cons '(q) '(a b c)) ; ==> '(c b a q)`

Comment: @Sylwester and in Racket `(foldl cons '(q) '(a b c)) => '(c b a q)`. so, there isn't an agreement on this.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez It's seldom a problem, but I can think of:  `(apply fold-left (lambda (acc . eles) ...) '() lsts)` which would be a challenge to do with the accumulator as the last element of a unknown number of arguments procedure.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez about map with foldl, what if I don't want to use "reverse" (without simple helpful scheme keywords) and just implement with logic(?), you know?

Comment: I mean, I try not to use - reverse, flip, append....- any of those can fix the order simply...

Comment: @user1915570 Then just use `foldr`. If you insist on using `foldl`, you're going to have to use `reverse`, or else implement `reverse` yourself by hand.

Comment: @user1915570 Chris is right, you simply can't implement `map` with `foldl` without reversing a list at some point...